# Google Chrome throws -Invalid Server Certificate- for any SSL

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https

Strange problem happening with me for the third time this month, when i restart my pc it's being solved:

Google Chrome throws -Invalid Server Certificate- for any secured website like Facebook or live or even for Gmail.
I'm using the latest version of chrome.
Does anyone have the same problem!

Comment: I've found a solution, it's a bug in Chrome happens after the system's hibernate, i solve it without restart by killing the chrome process 'End Process Tree for chrome.exe'


I'm using Windows 7 Home premium, Chrome v18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its in news.. Google chrome hit by ssl bug.

http://www.slashgear.com/google-chrome-hit-by-ssl-bug-restricting-google-services-06221921/

We need to wait for security update.

**Update**:

after checking this [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118706). I finally solved it:

You need to follow 2 steps only:

1. Delete all cache from chrome .
2. Close the chrome by pressing ctrl +w.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution, it's a bug in Chrome happens after the system's hibernate, i solve it without restart by killing the chrome process 'End Process Tree for chrome.exe'

I'm using Windows 7 Home premium, Chrome v18.

Comment: The same happened right now to my Version 53.0.2785.89 (64-bit)
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Your hint helped me "fixing" the error. Thx. 4 years after, your answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Chrome did have a bug at one point -

Close the site with cert issue.
Click on 3 dots at the top right to get to settings --> About --> update Chrome - It will ask you to relaunch for the update to take effect.. Accept.

Browse to the site again - if you still have an issue - Verify your certificate using sslshopper or Digicert SSL checkers free tools to make sure your cert is properly installed.